# react native azure dev ops pipeline build failure

Tags: reactjs, azure, react-native, azure-pipelines, devops

React native build fails in pipeline on IOS step

We run ios in the azure devops pipeline with `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release`

```
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.201.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /Users/runner/work/_temp/ae9db986-f3a7-4f07-a6ba-d2250f5bfb5a.sh
info Found Xcode workspace "Navitus.xcworkspace"
The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10827 "kLSNoExecutableErr: The executable is missing" UserInfo={_LSLine=3878, _LSFunction=_LSOpenStuffCallLocal}
error Command failed: open /Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app --args -CurrentDeviceUDID EA2BA6D4-C48C-4C19-A440-403677562929
The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10827 "kLSNoExecutableErr: The executable is missing" UserInfo={_LSLine=3878, _LSFunction=_LSOpenStuffCallLocal}
.
Error: Command failed: open /Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app --args -CurrentDeviceUDID EA2BA6D4-C48C-4C19-A440-403677562929
The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10827 "kLSNoExecutableErr: The executable is missing" UserInfo={_LSLine=3878, _LSFunction=_LSOpenStuffCallLocal}

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:790:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:827:15)
    at runOnSimulator (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:208:28)
    at Object.runIOS [as func] (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:121:12)
    at Command.handleAction (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:23)
    at Command.listener (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Command.parseArgs (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/commander/index.js:651:12)
    at Command.parse (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/commander/index.js:474:21)
    at setupAndRun (/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:271:24)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: iOS Build
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve `"kLSNoExecutableErr: The executable is missing"`, you can try the following workarounds according to [dsame](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/4545):

**[retry](https://github.com/dsame/actions-demo/runs/4289314472?check_suite_focus=true)**:

```
        steps:
            - name: Open Simulator app
              run: |
                while ! open -Fn /Applications/Xcode_${{ matrix.xcode }}.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app; do
                  echo "Retry"
                done
                echo "Success"
```

**[Update launch database](https://github.com/dsame/actions-demo/actions/runs/1491177047)**:

```
        steps:
            - name: Open Simulator app
              run: |
                /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -f /Applications/Xcode_${{ matrix.xcode }}.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
                open -Fn /Applications/Xcode_${{ matrix.xcode }}.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
```

Reference: [Launch Services database problems: correcting and rebuilding](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/08/11/launch-services-database-problems-correcting-and-rebuilding/)